# FTP upload through Wordpress admin menu tab not working

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp

I've added an admin menu tab to upload a file via the Wordpress backend. I was going to adapt some php code I found at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php

Only problem... I can't even get it to work as-is. It connects to the ftp server, but the file upload always fails. I've tried a number of variations. Any ideas?

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'ftp_menu' );

function ftp_menu() {
    add_menu_page( 'FTP Options', 'FTP', 'manage_options', 'ftp-options', 'ftp_options' );
}

function ftp_options() {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
        wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
    }
    if(isset($_POST['ftp']))
     {
        $ftp = $_POST['ftp'];
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
        $filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];
        $tmp = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $d = $_POST['des'];

        $connect = ftp_connect($ftp)or die("Unable to connect to host");
        ftp_login($connect,$username,$pwd)or die("Authorization Failed");
        echo "Connected!<br/>";                

        if(!$filename)
            {
                echo "Please select a file";
            }
        else
            {
                ftp_put($connect,$filename,$tmp,FTP_BINARY)or die("Unable to upload");
                        echo"File successfully uploaded to FTP";
            }
    }

?>
<div class="main">
    <h1>FTP</h1>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="text" name="ftp" placeholder="FTP link"/><br/>
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/><br/>
        <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password"/><br/>
        <input type="file" name="file" /><br/>
        <input type="text" name="des" placeholder="Destination"  /><br/>
        <br/><input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
    </form>
</div>
<?php
}
```

Ultimately, I want to be able to just click a single button and upload a csv file from my website to a remote FTP directory. (So the source file will be a full url and the destination an ftp folder.) Thanks for any help!